# View sharing/composers don't work correctly from the BaseController

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having issues where the data I attempt to bind to my views only work when I register the binding in certain locations.

For example, when I attempt to bind in the `App::before()` filter, it works and `successMessages` is available in all views.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    View::share('successMessages', array('All good', 'Nailed it', 'Perfect'));
});
```

However, when I attempt to do it in the BaseController constructor (which all controllers inherit from), I get a variable not found error.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        View::share('successMessages', array('All good', 'Nailed it', 'Perfect'));
    }
}
```

The same issue exists when I attempt to use a view composer instead of the `View::share()` method.

```
View::composer(array('layouts.application', 'layouts.home'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('successMessages', array('All good', 'Nailed it', 'Perfect'));
});
```

Any idea why these will register in the `App::before()` filter but not the controller constructor, where I think they should probably belong?

Comment: Perhaps you should call the parent constructor from the child controller? `parent::__construct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case passing the messages to the controller, you are most probably getting the variable not found in routes that are NOT using a controller, therefore BaseController is not constructed.

For example, this (checked) works as you would have wanted (leaving the BaseController as you have it):

```
Route::get('testit',
array('as' => 'testing',  'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Site\SomeController@gsomeMethod')
```

);

For any method in a controller that inherits from BaseController and constructs a view, $successMessages will be available in the view.

Comment: Looks like you were right - silly oversight on my part. The routes that were being parsed by callbacks in `routes.php` instead of being passed to a controller were causing the issue.

Comment: Happens to everyone :) glad it helped.